# facing problem in c# calculator operator pressed it shows calculates result while pressing another operator

Tags: c#

I am new to c# programming.I am building a simple calculator but when i add two numbers and press operator(+) button it adds two numbers but when i again press another operator it just adds the previous value like 2+2= 4 and if i press (-) operator after that it just shows result = 8  , please help me to get out of this.
thanks.

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Calculator
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
          double value  = 0;
          string operation = "";
          bool opt_pressed = false;



            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if ((txtMain.Text == "0") || (opt_pressed))
                    txtMain.Clear();
                Button a = (Button)sender;
                opt_pressed = false;
                if (a.Text == ".")
                {
                    if (!txtMain.Text.Contains("."))
                        txtMain.Text = txtMain.Text + a.Text;


                }


                else
                {
                    txtMain.Text = txtMain.Text + a.Text;

                }

            }

            private void txtMain_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {   
                txtMain.Clear();
                value = 0;
                label1.Text = "";





            }

            private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {   
                Button b = (Button)sender;

                if (value != 0)
             {
                equal.PerformClick();
                operation = b.Text;

                label1.Text = value + " " + operation;
                opt_pressed = true;

             }
                else 

        {       operation = b.Text;
                value = double.Parse(txtMain.Text);

                label1.Text = value + " " + operation;
                opt_pressed = true;
        }

            }

            private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                switch (operation) 
                {
                    case  "+":

                        txtMain.Text = (value + double.Parse(txtMain.Text)).ToString();
                        break;
                    case "-":

                        txtMain.Text = (value - double.Parse(txtMain.Text)).ToString();
                        break;
                    case "/":

                        txtMain.Text = (value / double.Parse(txtMain.Text)).ToString();
                        break;
                    case "*":

                        txtMain.Text = (value * double.Parse(txtMain.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

               }

                value = double.Parse(txtMain.Text);
                label1.Text = "";


            }

            private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                Button a = (Button)sender;

                button1.PerformClick();
                operation = a.Text;

            }




        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged this, if not do so [Tutorial: Learn to debug using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017)